# How to iterate over key values of a Kafka Streams Table

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm new to Kafka streams and I tried to iterate over items in a kafka Streams table via the keyValueStore:

The idea is to create a Ktable (I've also tried with a globalKTable) with a KeyValueStore.
Then a separated thread is in charge to read the content of the KeyValueStore in order to iterate over last value of each key.

```
      val streamProperties: Properties = {
      val p = new Properties()
      p.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "test-application")
      p.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, config.getStringList("kafka.bootstrap.servers").toList.mkString(","))
      p.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String.getClass.getName)
      p.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.ByteArray.getClass.getName)
      p.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")
      p
    }

    val builder: StreamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder()
    import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized
    import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.KeyValueStore


    val globalTable = builder.table("test",
      Materialized
        .as[String, Array[Byte], KeyValueStore[org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes, Array[Byte]]]("TestStore")
        .withCachingDisabled()
        .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
        .withValueSerde(Serdes.ByteArray())
    )

    val streams: KafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), streamProperties)
    streams.start()

    val ex = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1)
    val task = new Runnable {
      def run() = {
        println("\n\n\n tick \n\n\n")
        try {
          val keyValueStore = streams.store(globalTable.queryableStoreName(), QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore())
          keyValueStore.all().toIterator.map { k =>
            print(k.key)
          }
        } catch {
          case _ => println("error")
        }
      }
    }
    val f = ex.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  }
}
```

In the thread the keyValueStore stays empty even when I produce items on topic "test".

Is there something I missed or didn't understand?

Comment: I cannot spot a obvious error. Check out the this example: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/tree/5.0.0-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/interactivequeries Hope this helps.

Comment: Some more info: A test-application-TestStore-changelog topic is created with changes but nothing to iterate on my keyValueStore

Comment: "tick" is printed regularly? What about "error"? Side remark: you need to close the iterator you get from `streams.store()` to avoid resource leaks.

Answer (score 0):

One thing missing is state directory location config:

```
p.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, "/tmp")
```

Without it Kafka Streams would not throw exception, but stateful things like global KTables would silently not work.

Comment: Not sure how that helps... That is the default property value